# How to deal with debounced input in Cypress tests?

Tags: reactjs, cypress, lodash, debouncing

What is the recommended approach for dealing with a debounced input in Cypress E2E tests.

For example, let's assume I have the following component that uses `lodash/debounce`

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

const DebouncedInput = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState("");

  // The debounced function
  const searchApi = useCallback(
    _.debounce(async (inputValue) => {
      setSearchResult(`User searched for: ${inputValue}`);
    }, 200),
    []
  );

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setQuery(e.target.value);
    searchApi(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={query}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Type something..."
      />
      {searchResult && <p>{searchResult}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DebouncedInput;
```

How would I go about making sure that my Cypress tests won't be flaky?

In my mind there are two ways:

- Dealing with cy.clock() and using cy.tick()

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="foo"]').type('hey').tick(250)
```

- Taking advantage of `cy.type` and the `delay` option

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="foo"]').type('hey', {delay: 250});
```

I tried both approaches and seem to work. But I am not sure if there is actually a recommended way to do this or if one apporach is better than the other.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `debounce()` is on the firing of the `searchApi()` function, the first example `.type('hey').tick(250)` will **fire only once** in the test

The lodash code uses `setTimeout()` internally so `clock()/tick()` will ensure the debounce does not fire until you tick, by which time all chars will be typed into the input.

But `.type('hey', {delay: 250})` limits the rate at which characters are typed, so at delay of 250 you will fire `searchApi()` for **every character in the typed string**.

---

At the moment, all you are doing is echoing the typed value to the page. I assume that you will actually perform a search call.

To test that your debounce is effective, add an intercept at the top of the test.

**tick() method**

```js
cy.intercept(searchUrl, {}).as('search')  // static reply so that API call time 
                                          // does not affect the result
 
cy.get('[data-cy="foo"]').type('hey').tick(250)

cy.wait('@search')

cy.wait(250)  // wait longer than debounce duration 
              // to catch any API call that occurs after the first

cy.get('@search.all').should('have.length', 1)  // assert only 1 call was made
```

**delay option**

```js
cy.intercept(searchUrl, {}).as('search')

cy.get('[data-cy="foo"]').type('hey', {delay: 250})

Cypress._.times(3, cy.wait('@search')  // wait on intercept 3 times 
                                       // once per char in the typed string

cy.wait(250)  // wait longer than debounce duration 

cy.get('@search.all').should('have.length', 3)  // assert only 3 calls made
```

Without a searchAPI call, you would need to spy on the `setSearchResult` function to see how many calls were made.

---

#### Without cy.intercept() on an API call

Technically @Alaa MH has a workable solution, but the example he gives isn't terrific.

If there is **no API call**, you can use `cy.wait()` because the waiting time is always going to be just a little longer than the debounce time (add a little for app internal javascript to process.

However, using `clock()/tick()` is the safest option, though.

```js
cy.clock()

cy.visit('/')

cy.get('[data-cy="foo"]').type('hey')

cy.get('div p').should('be.empty')  // since searchResult is initally empty

cy.tick(250)

cy.get('div p').should('have.text', 'hey')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cy.wait(The same delay period of the used debounce).

```
_.debounce((searchValue: string) => {
 ...       
}, 5000)


//in search.cy.js
it("assert no items are existing", () => {
  cy.get("[data-test=search-input]").type("random 12345...");
  cy.wait(5000);
  cy.get(".no-items-panel").should("exist");
});
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid this as it is listed as an anti-pattern in the [official documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Unnecessary-Waiting)!